# QT QSqlDatabase может быть создан только один раз

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Есть класс:

```
class DataBase
{
protected:
bool DataBase::connectToDB()
{
    db.setHostName(DBHOSTNAME);
    db.setDatabaseName(DBNAME);
    db.setUserName(DBUSERNAME);
    db.setPassword(DBPASSWORD);
    return db.open();
}
    QSqlQuery query;
private:
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL3");
    const QString DBHOSTNAME = "****",
            DBUSERNAME = "****",
            DBPASSWORD = "****",
            DBNAME = "****";
};
```

И

```
class DataBaseManager: public DataBase
{
public:
    QVector<QVariant> getItem(const QString name);
    QVector<QVariant> getItem(const QString name, const QString where, const QString whereData);
// другие функции
};
```

В классе стартового окна

```
DataBaseManager ManagerDB;
```

Но, нужно использовать `DataBaseManager` в нескольких формах. Но ловлю:

> QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection
>   'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to
>   work.

> QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name
>   'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.

Понимаю, что нужно использовать `QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL3");` только один раз в программе, но не понимаю как реализовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, вам поможет применение [singleton](http://cpp-reference.ru/patterns/creational-patterns/singleton/) паттерна

```
static DataBaseManager& getInstance() {
    static DataBaseManager  instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Будьте осторожны с применением данного паттерна с библиотекой Qt! Наследник QObject, хранимый статично, должен получать nullptr в качестве класса-владельца в параметрах конструктора: в противном случае есть рист получить Heap Corruption из-за штатной системы [сборки мусора](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html)

Comment: Конструктор всё равно будет вызван: если есть неуверенность в понимании пошаманьте с qDebug()

Answer (score 2):

Лучше в отдельной инициализирующей член-функции главного окна или специализированного класса один раз выполнить

```
//один раз создаёт соединение, которое можно получить в любой точке программы
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL3"); 
db.setHostName(DBHOSTNAME);
db.setDatabaseName(DBNAME);
db.setUserName(DBUSERNAME);
db.setPassword(DBPASSWORD);
db.open();
```

и затем где надо использовать статическую функцию `QSqlDatabase::database()` для получения экземпляра ранее созданного соединения к БД, предварительно проверяя его на `isValid()`.

Ошибка как раз и возникает, т.к. каждый раз при создании экземпляра `DataBase` снова вызывается статический метод `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL3");`

> QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name
>   'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.

А тут стоит обратить внимание на время жизни экземпляра `QSqlDatabase`, чтобы избежать утечек ресурсов.

> QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection
>   'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to
>   work.