# Можно ли инициализировать статическое поле класса значением из БД

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

Дано: Qt, SQLite.
Константные статические поля класса которые прекрасно инициализируются примерно вот так:

```
const Cell Act::_subaccountcell = Cell("A15");
```

Далее делаю так:

```
const Cell Act::_subaccountcell = magicCell(subaccountcell);
```

получаю:

> QSqlQuery::exec: database not open  QSqlQuery::value: not positioned
>   on a valid record  ASSERT: "uint(i) < uint(size())" in file
>   ....\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\mingw53_32\include\QtCore/qstring.h, line 887 
>   Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.  Invalid parameter
>   passed to C runtime function.

Добавляю в функцию magicCell подключение к базе данных которое присутствует также в main, получаю:

> The program has unexpectedly finished. Процесс был завершён
>   принудительно.

Возвращаю инициализацию к изначальному варианту и все работает хоть и жалуется:

> QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name
>   'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на документацию класса `Cell`

Comment: я ее еще не написал)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985929/214561

Comment: Никак не догоняю. До исправлений в программе я в main один раз создавал подключение и после этого оно у меня работало и не требовалось никаких экземпляров подключения. Но инициализация статических полей идет до функции main и я не понимаю как мне поможет тот ответ. Множественные попытки подключения хоть и выдают сообщения но программу не роняют сами по себе.

Comment: Не знаю, как у вас идёт инициализация статических переменных, но загляните [сюда](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). Они иногда может и не роняют, а иногда и роняют. Делайте правильно сразу.

Answer (score 0):

Как обычно дело было не в бобине. При создании подключения к базе данных функция обращалась к переменной пути до этой базы которой на тот момент не существовало.

Ну ОК. Ответ: можно. Для этого надо всего лишь...

... не быть криворуким дебилом как я.
Понятно было, что несколько раз вызывать QSqlDatabase::addDatabase() не лучшая идея. Что в комментарии по своей ссылке хотел сказать magrif я так и не догнал, но [вот это](http://cpp-reference.ru/patterns/creational-patterns/singleton/) было понятно. Запилил вариант Мэйерса, в конструктор по умолчанию кинул подключение к БД, getInstance() в magicCell(). Подключение стало запускаться только один раз, но основную проблему это не решило, программа все также падала. И тут меня осенила гениальная мысль о существовании отладки. Как только выполнение замерло на строчке

```
db.setDatabaseName(getDBPath().absolutePath() + '/' + "data.db");
```

я понял что структура path, где должны находиться директории, объявлена static в другом файле, а какие то осмысленные значения в ней появляются только в функции main(). Не долго думая применил тот же патерн для присвоения значений путей полям этой структуры и все заработало. Осталось только понять как получить директорию приложения до запуска main() для полного счастья.

Comment: А не проще всю инициализацию сделать из первой строки в main()?

Comment: @avp если я правильно мыслю можно заменить статические поля класса на статические переменные в методе класса и инициализировать их при запуске метода те по факту будет при создании объекта?

Comment: Например, так. Или вы делаете просто статический указатель на объект и инициализируете его в функции, которая создает объект и вы вызываете ее один раз в начале main. Далее вся работа идет через этот указатель.